# Reading a text file in vba and modifying a certain cell depending on the user input in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I started coding in vba today for the first time. My code should ask for a user input first and then read from a text file. If the user input matches the 100 number in the text file it should then populate a certain cell with whatever is next to the 100 number, until the - in the worksheet. If it is GHF897-HTU71L then it should populate the cell until GHF897.

Here is the text file

```
HGJDJS UFHFHFHB HHGG 0001    100000896765    GHF897-HTU71L-7811-YTHIN            U1P903678    GHF897_0000000016       000001    |||||||    W69      000001    |||||||---    X72    BAL TAG    000002    |||||||    X75    CONFIG    000001    |||||||

 GFHRTE 0001    100657853125   FGD867-YTURGL-TT55-YTHU/NH7            U1P903679    HFJDJH1_0000000015
```

---

```
Sub readFile()
    Dim myValue As Variant

    myValue = InputBox("Please Enter/Scan the order number", "Order Number")

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const strFileName As String = "C:\text2.txt"

    FileNum = FreeFile

    Open strFileName For Input As #FileNum

    Line Input #FileNum, StrBuffer

    i = 0

    Do Until EOF(1)
        arr = Split(StrBuffer, vbTab)

        If arr(i) = myValue Then Range("D4").Value = arr(i + 1)

        i = i + 1

        'End If
    Loop

    Close #1
End Sub
```

It should populate the cell "d4" with the value of arr(i+1)

Comment: Side issue: you have got a file handle `#FileNum` then are using `EOF(1)` and `Close #1`,  should be `EOF(#FileNum)` and `Close #FileNum`

Answer (score 0):

If your "100 number" is slways within a string such as 'GHF897-' (letter, letter, letter, number, number, number, dash) you can use RegEx to look for it.  The function below searches input string for a match and returns it.  You should be able to manipulate the output string to suit your needs.  There is a multitude of RegEx tutorial which can be easily found online or you can search StackOverflow for more examples and ideas.

```
Function MatchNumber(str As String) As String

    Dim intNo As Integer
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim obj As Object

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RegEx.Pattern = "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]-"

    Set obj = RegEx.Execute(str)

    MatchNumber = obj(0)

End Function
```