# Extracting specific words from Textpad and writing it in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract numbers after specific words from TextPad to Excel columns.

Example TextPad file.

```
INFO CRITERIA is MATCHED. DISPLAY ID 123456 AND AT T=369   
MAY BE MATCHING OR MAY NOT BE
INFO CRITERIA is MATCHED. DISPLAY ID 12345678 AND AT T=3698  
SEVERAL PACKAGES TO BE FOLLOWED
WAIT UNTIL THE PROCESS FINISHES
INFO CRITERIA is MATCHED. DISPLAY ID 123 AND AT T=32
REGARDING THE TIMINGS..
```

I want to extract the DISPLAY ID and the time (T=) to different columns in Excel.

Below is the code I tried.

How to use an array and for loop? How to read the remaining lines? If we use Mid function and the number of characters after "T=" varies in each line, it will be difficult to get the numbers correct.

```
Sub Extract()
Dim myFile As String, _
    text As String, _
    textline As String, _
    DISPLAY As Integer, _
    TIME As Integer

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        text = text & textline
    Loop
    DISPLAY = InStr(text, "DISPLAY ID")
    TIME = InStr(text, "AT T=")
    Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, DISPLAY + 10, 8)
    Range("B1").Value = Mid(text, TIME + 5, 6)
End Sub
```

Comment: Which code have you tried so far? You must show some work or pre-work of your own. The community isn't providing plain solutions to people just needing some final code. That would be an issue to hire someone. But add your work and everything is fine.

Comment: I was constantly trying to learn the keywords and other terms. Just learnt MID Function and I was able to at least start with it. I was looking for some clues to the problem as I did not know where and how to start. Just gone through so many forums and I was able to atleast add some code of mine.

Comment: Consider using RegEx to find and extract your keywords - I've shown an example of how to do it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229757/reading-a-text-file-in-vba-and-modifying-a-certain-cell-depending-on-the-user-in/56230103#56230103 You should have no problems finding more tutorials and examples.  Let us know if you are still stuck after you try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code refactored to add the required loop, and deal with a number of other issues.

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim myFile As Variant ' Handle Cancel
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim idx As Long     ' separate position from data
    Dim DisplayName As String
    Dim DisplayFound As Boolean 'flag for if rw should be incremented
    Dim TimeName As String
    Dim TimeFound As Boolean
    Dim FNum As Integer ' FreeFile returns an Integer
    Dim rw As Long      'counter for output row
    Dim ws As Worksheet ' best to avoid Active objects

    On Error GoTo EH ' ensure file is closed

    ' speed thing up a bit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    DisplayName = "DISPLAY ID"
    TimeName = "AT T="

    rw = 1 ' start output at row 1
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If myFile = False Then GoTo CleanUp ' handle cancel
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or whatever sheet you need

    FNum = FreeFile
    Open myFile For Input As #FNum
    With ws
        Do Until EOF(FNum)
            Line Input #FNum, textline

            DisplayFound = False
            TimeFound = False
            idx = InStr(textline, DisplayName)
            If idx Then ' DisplayName was found
                text = Trim(Mid$(textline, idx + Len(DisplayName)))
                idx = InStr(text, " ")
                If idx Then  'allow for possibility  value is at end of string
                    text = Trim(Left$(text, idx - 1))
                End If
                .Cells(rw, 1).Value = text
                DisplayFound = True
            End If
            idx = InStr(textline, TimeName)
            If idx Then ' TimeName was found
                text = Trim(Mid$(textline, idx + Len(TimeName)))
                idx = InStr(text, " ")
                If idx Then  'allow for possibility  value is at end of string
                    text = Trim(Left$(text, idx - 1))
                End If
                .Cells(rw, 2).Value = text
                TimeFound = True
            End If
            If DisplayFound Or TimeFound Then
                rw = rw + 1  'increment output row
            End If
        Loop
    End With
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #FNum
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    'Add Error Handling here

    'Then clean up
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

Note that writing directly to the sheet like this one cell at a time may be too slow, especially if you are processing many files, or the files are large.  If it is too slow for your needs, consider transitioning to a Variant Array approach (many examples of that here on SO)

Comment: Extraordinary .

Comment: extra ordinary... i am able to learn new functions...I have a small doubt.. what if the the char aftr T= is a combination of alpbabet and numbers like this "AT T= 0.13D1". . ..Could yu pl throw some light on

Comment: If extracted data might be Strings (or floating point numbers) then remove type casting to Long.  Answer edited